# Can anyone tell how to speed up my vuejs app?

Tags: vuex, vuejs3

I am a noob in vuejs. This piece of my code is making my app very slow.

```html
<div v-for="(attribute, i) in attributes" :key="i">
  <div>{{ AttributeClicked(attribute) }}</div>
</div>
```

This is the function:

```js
AttributeClicked(attribute) {
  this.$store.commit("entities/Attribute/select", attribute.id);
}
```

This is the mutation:

```js
mutations: {
  select(state, id) {
    let selection = Attribute.find(id);
    Attribute.update({
      where: (a) => a.selected,
      data: {
        selected: false
      }
    });
    if (selection !== null) {
      Attribute.update({
        where: id,
        data: {
          selected: true
        }
      })
    }
  },
}
```

The purpose of this code is to make a webpage like this one https://www.tesla.com/models/design#overview
My objective is for example to show the 5 options below Paint attribute when the page loads.

Can anyone tell me how to speed up this app?

Comment: 1) What is the purpose of this code?  2) Can you show the mutation?

Comment: Maybe you want to call AttributeClicked function when user click on this attribute ?  <div @click="AttributeClicked(attribute)">{{ attribute }}</div>

Comment: @Radeanu, It works that way. But I want to display the options without clicking on the attribute.

Comment: I don't get it, if you want to display value from store, use getters instead.

Comment: In v-for, where the attributes come from, and where did you define Attribute in mutation ?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to provide more code or info to get to what you want to be doing, but with the code provided I can see several issues. Maybe understanding the problems will help you get to the solution you are looking for.

- You've got a function inside the template, these are fine to pass to event handles such as `@click`, but they can have a negative effect on performance. Whenever you have the template re-render (which happens when certain data changes) it will re-run the functions. In this case you run the function as many times as you have `attributes`, and if any if the `AttributeClicked` method causes a reactivity update to propagate to this template, you will have an endless loop.
- looks like you're calling a mutation when an action may be more appropriate. Mutations are strictly for updating state in a synchronous manner. The `select` mutation does not mutate the state, so it's simply wrong to put it in there. Even though it may work, vuex is a tool that not only stores global state, but also organizes it in an opinionated way. If you're going to go against the intended design, you may find it easier to just avoid using it.

I suspect you may be able to execute `AttributeClicked(attribute)` one time during component mount.